# jquery today's timetable defining start time

Tags: jquery

I am using today's timetable plugin on my website. Problem is, starting time is the current time. But I want it to define it to a fixed time (i.e. 10:00). How can I do it?

plugin url with instructions (very limited):
http://www.cod3.net/timetable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'How to use it' section, it says that you can use the 'goTo' method to go to specific hour.

```
nameOfYourVar.goTo(hour);
```

Comment: hi,

thank you for responding. Yes but I want it start at a that time, placing a link wont help.

Comment: What do you mean by 'placing a link wont help?' You don't have to call the 'gotTo' method on click of a link, you can call it right after you initialize your timetable variable.

Comment: Well I tried it as the following code but it does not work, events dissappear.
<script type="text/javascript">
var Monday = new Timetable("mondayTable").goTo(9.3);
Monday.addEvent("Breakfast & Registration", 8, 0.45);
Monday.addEvent("<img style='float:left' alt='Queens of the Stone Age' src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/QOTSA_mg_5853.jpg/90px-QOTSA_mg_5853.jpg' />Opening Remarks<br /><a target='_blank' href='http://www.qotsa.com'>Official website</a><br /><a target='_blank' href='http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QOTSA'>Wikipedia page</a>", 9, 1);

</script>